# Is it possible to reduce memory consumption of a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, ram

I'm working on a Windows service using C# and trying to release the memory my service consumes after the execution is done and it's waiting to execute once more after the interval has passed.

I was trying to set `Process.MinimumWorkingSetSize` and `Process.MaximumWorkingSetSize` to 1 but keep getting unwanted behavior like termination of the process.

If what I'm doing is not pointing in the right direction can someone please help me with this? I would deeply appreciate any help,

Best Regards

Jose

Comment: Note that the fact that it is a service is irrelevant, it has no effect on memory management.

Answer (score 1):

You generally should not need to worry about managing memory in c#.

If your service's memory footprint grows over time, you likely have an architectural problem (basically memory leak) with objects remaining referenced and thereby not able to be collected by the garbage collector.